# Express session not storing cookies on ios/safari browser, but works fine on android

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I have been facing this issue for weeks now, am trying to login to my app on IOS device, it turns out that express-session did not store cookies in the browser, for this reason, I was unable to login. But I was able to login on my android device and laptop. But am still unable to access the app on safari on my android device.

My frontend stack is Nextjs, and Nodejs with express for my backend.
Backend was deployed on heroku and frontend was deployed on netlify

Pls how do I solve this problem. Here is what my code looks like. I did like my app to work on all browser.

============================Server.js=====================================

```
import express from "express"
import rootRoute from "./src/root_Route.js"
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser"
import passport from "passport"
import connectPgSimple from "connect-pg-simple"
import session from "express-session"
import dotenv from "dotenv"
import cors from "cors"
import "./src/LIB/DB-Client.js"
import "./src/PASSPORT_STRATEGY/google-auth-strategy.js"
import "./src/PASSPORT_STRATEGY/facebook-auth-strategy.js"
import { scheduleJob } from "node-schedule"
import pool from "./src/LIB/DB-Client.js"
dotenv.config()
const app = express()


const connection = process.env.PRODUCTION !== "production" ? process.env.DEV_DATABASE_URL : process.env.DATABASE_URL

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://localhost:3000", "https://nairaonly-frontend.netlify.app"],
    credentials: true,
    methods: "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE",
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  })
)
const PgStore = connectPgSimple(session)
const store = new PgStore({ conString: connection, schemaName: "hidden", createTableIfMissing: true })

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.set("trust proxy", 1)

app.use(
  session({
    store: store,
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: true,
    proxy: true,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'none' : 'lax',
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : false,
    },
  })
)

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("API Running...")
})

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
rootRoute(app)

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000

app.listen(PORT, (req, res) => console.log(`Server running on PORT:${PORT}...`))
```

Answer (score 1):

I get this solved by registering a domain name, and added a subdomain which was used for my backend and the domain itself for my frontend. I then point the DNS to each other. This solve the issue

Comment: So you did backend.fakedomain.com and frontend.fakedomain.com ? Any additional setup for the session object?

Comment: Hey did you ever figure this out? I think i'm facing the same issue now. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have this exact same issue, working with android but not ios. I tried all of the cookie options but none seem to work. Did you manage to fix this without creating a domain?